# Loss curve saturates at 1.0 for MNIST dataset using Tensorflow.js

Tags: mnist, tensorflow.js

data.js

```
    /**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2018 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 * =============================================================================
 */

const IMAGE_SIZE = 784;
const NUM_CLASSES = 10;
const NUM_DATASET_ELEMENTS = 65000;

const TRAIN_TEST_RATIO = 5 / 6;

const NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS = Math.floor(TRAIN_TEST_RATIO * NUM_DATASET_ELEMENTS);
const NUM_TEST_ELEMENTS = NUM_DATASET_ELEMENTS - NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS;

const MNIST_IMAGES_SPRITE_PATH =
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/learnjs-data/model-builder/mnist_images.png';
const MNIST_LABELS_PATH =
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/learnjs-data/model-builder/mnist_labels_uint8';

/**
 * A class that fetches the sprited MNIST dataset and returns shuffled batches.
 *
 * NOTE: This will get much easier. For now, we do data fetching and
 * manipulation manually.
 */
export class MnistData {
  constructor() {
    this.shuffledTrainIndex = 0;
    this.shuffledTestIndex = 0;
  }

  async load() {
    // Make a request for the MNIST sprited image.
    const img = new Image();
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const imgRequest = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      img.crossOrigin = '';
      img.onload = () => {
        img.width = img.naturalWidth;
        img.height = img.naturalHeight;

        const datasetBytesBuffer =
            new ArrayBuffer(NUM_DATASET_ELEMENTS * IMAGE_SIZE * 4);

        const chunkSize = 5000;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = chunkSize;

        for (let i = 0; i < NUM_DATASET_ELEMENTS / chunkSize; i++) {
          const datasetBytesView = new Float32Array(
              datasetBytesBuffer, i * IMAGE_SIZE * chunkSize * 4,
              IMAGE_SIZE * chunkSize);
          ctx.drawImage(
              img, 0, i * chunkSize, img.width, chunkSize, 0, 0, img.width,
              chunkSize);

          const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

          for (let j = 0; j < imageData.data.length / 4; j++) {
            // All channels hold an equal value since the image is grayscale, so
            // just read the red channel.
            datasetBytesView[j] = imageData.data[j * 4] / 255;
          }
        }
        this.datasetImages = new Float32Array(datasetBytesBuffer);

        resolve();
      };
      img.src = MNIST_IMAGES_SPRITE_PATH;
    });

    const labelsRequest = fetch(MNIST_LABELS_PATH);
    const [imgResponse, labelsResponse] =
        await Promise.all([imgRequest, labelsRequest]);

    this.datasetLabels = new Uint8Array(await labelsResponse.arrayBuffer());

    // Create shuffled indices into the train/test set for when we select a
    // random dataset element for training / validation.
    this.trainIndices = tf.util.createShuffledIndices(NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS);
    this.testIndices = tf.util.createShuffledIndices(NUM_TEST_ELEMENTS);

    // Slice the the images and labels into train and test sets.
    this.trainImages =
        this.datasetImages.slice(0, IMAGE_SIZE * NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS);
    this.testImages = this.datasetImages.slice(IMAGE_SIZE * NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS);
    this.trainLabels =
        this.datasetLabels.slice(0, NUM_CLASSES * NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS);
    this.testLabels =
        this.datasetLabels.slice(NUM_CLASSES * NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS);
  }

  nextTrainBatch(batchSize) {
    return this.nextBatch(
        batchSize, [this.trainImages, this.trainLabels], () => {
          this.shuffledTrainIndex =
              (this.shuffledTrainIndex + 1) % this.trainIndices.length;
          return this.trainIndices[this.shuffledTrainIndex];
        });
  }

  nextTestBatch(batchSize) {
    return this.nextBatch(batchSize, [this.testImages, this.testLabels], () => {
      this.shuffledTestIndex =
          (this.shuffledTestIndex + 1) % this.testIndices.length;
      return this.testIndices[this.shuffledTestIndex];
    });
  }

  nextBatch(batchSize, data, index) {
    const batchImagesArray = new Float32Array(batchSize * IMAGE_SIZE);
    const batchLabelsArray = new Uint8Array(batchSize * NUM_CLASSES);

    for (let i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
      const idx = index();

      const image =
          data[0].slice(idx * IMAGE_SIZE, idx * IMAGE_SIZE + IMAGE_SIZE);
      batchImagesArray.set(image, i * IMAGE_SIZE);

      const label =
          data[1].slice(idx * NUM_CLASSES, idx * NUM_CLASSES + NUM_CLASSES);
      batchLabelsArray.set(label, i * NUM_CLASSES);
    }

    const xs = tf.tensor2d(batchImagesArray, [batchSize, IMAGE_SIZE]);
    const labels = tf.tensor2d(batchLabelsArray, [batchSize, NUM_CLASSES]);

    return {xs, labels};
  }
}
```

script.js

```
    import {MnistData} from './data.js';
var canvas,ctx,saveButton,clearButton;
var pos={x:0,y:0};
var rawImage;
var model;

function getModel()
{
    model=tf.sequential();
    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({inputShape:[28,28,1],kernelSize:3,filters:8,activation:'relu'}));
    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize:[2,2]}));
    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({filters:16,kernelSize:3,activation:'relu'}));
    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize:[2,2]}));
    model.add(tf.layers.flatten());
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units:128,activation:'sigmoid'}));
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units:10,activation:'softmax'}));

    model.compile({optimizer:tf.train.adam(),loss:'categoricalCrossentropy',metrics:['accuracy']});

    return model;

}

async function train(model,data){
    const metrics=['loss', 'val_loss', 'acc', 'val_acc'];
    const container={name:'Model training',styles:{height:'640px'}};
    const fitCallbacks=tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(container,metrics);

    const BATCH_SIZE = 512;
    const TRAIN_DATA_SIZE = 5500;
    const TEST_DATA_SIZE = 1000;

    const [trainXs,trainYs]=tf.tidy(()=>
                                   {
        const d=data.nextTrainBatch(TRAIN_DATA_SIZE);
        return[
            d.xs.reshape([TRAIN_DATA_SIZE,28,28,1]),
            d.labels
        ];
    });

    const [testXs,testYs]=tf.tidy(()=>{
        const d=data.nextTestBatch(TEST_DATA_SIZE);
        return[
            d.xs.reshape([TEST_DATA_SIZE,28,28,1]),
            d.labels
        ];
    });

    return model.fit(trainXs,trainYs,{
        batchSize:BATCH_SIZE,
        validationData:[testXs,testYs],
        epochs:20,
        shuffle:true,
        callbacks:fitCallbacks
    });

}

function setPosition(e){
    pos.x=e.clientX-100;
    pos.y=e.clientY-100;
}

function draw(e)
{
    if(e.buttons!=1)return ;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth=24;
    ctx.lineCap='round';
    ctx.strokeStyle='white';
    ctx.moveTo(pos.x,pos.y);
    setPosition(e);
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x,pos.y)
    ctx.stroke();

    rawImage.src=canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}

function erase()
{
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,280,280);
}

function save()
{
    var raw=tf.browser.fromPixels(rawImage,1);
    var resized=tf.image.resizeBilinear(raw,[28,28]);
    var tensor=resized.expandDims(0);

    var prediction=model.predict(tensor);
    var pIndex=tf.argMax(prediction,1).dataSync();

    alert(pIndex);
}

function init()
{
    canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
    rawImage=document.getElementById('canvasimg');
    ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,280,280);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",draw);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",setPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseenter",setPosition);
    saveButton=document.getElementById('sb');
    saveButton.addEventListener("click",save);
    clearButton=document.getElementById('cb');
    clearButton.addEventListener("click",erase);


}

async function run()
{
    const data=new MnistData();
    await data.load();
    const model=getModel();
    tfvis.show.modelSummary({name:'Model Architecture'},model);
    await train(model,data);
    init();
    alert("Training is done, try classifying...");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
```

mnist.htm

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-vis"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    <h1> Handwritten character recognition</h1>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="280" height="280" style="position:absolute;top:100;left:100;border:8px solid;"></canvas>
    <img id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left=52%;width:280;height=280;display:none;">
    <input type="button" value="classify" id="sb" size="48" style="position:absolute;top:400;left:100;">
    <input type="button" value="clear" id="cb" size="23" style="position:absolute;top:400;left:180;">

    <script src="data.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I tried to make a handwritten digits classifier which recognizes digits based on what we draw on canvas of web page. But while training my loss curve saturates at 1.0 and my accuracy saturates at 60%. So I tried changing the activation function of the 128 nodes dense layer from relu to sigmoid. Even after changing that my loss saturates at 1.0. Please help me out.[image: I have added the picture of my loss plot]

Answer (score 0):

There are models that have been defined to classify mnist dataset [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/master/mnist/index.js) and [there](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-classfication/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4). If you want to rewrite your own model, then you will need to compare it against those official models that will serve as a baseline.